# Ajax com AntiForgeryToken não passa os dados

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

Estou com dificuldade de colocar o `AntiForgeryToken` no meu data do `json`. Segue o código que passo a informação dos meus dados para o `controller` sem problemas.

```
 var todos_servicos = {
        ServicoFornecedor,
        ServicoDesabilitado: $("#ServicoDesabilitado").val(),
        CodigoInterno: $("#CodigoInterno").val(),
        Descricao: $("#Descricao").val(),
        Observacoes: $("#Observacoes").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ServicosTerceiros/SalvarServicos', 
        dataType: "json", 
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache: false, 
        data: JSON.stringify(todos_servicos), // passar os parametros
        success: function (data) {
```

Para recuperar o `AntiForgeryToken` fiz assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gettoken() {
    var token = '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()';
    token = $(token).val();
    return token;
}
```

Agora quando eu uso o data para enviar o `token` me apresenta o seguinte erro:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)"

Já fiz várias tentativas no meu data, segue elas:

```
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(todos_servicos);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ServicosTerceiros/SalvarServicos', 
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST", 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
        cache: false, 
        data: { __RequestVerificationToken: gettoken(), jsonString }, // passar os parametros
        success: function (data) {
```

No meu `controller`:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SalvarServicos(DTO.ServicosTerceiros jsonString)
{
    // codigo
}
```

Declaração no view:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: Na sua ação você colocou `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` ?

Comment: sim, atualizei a minha pergunta

Answer (score 0):

no envio do ajax, procure passar assim

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ServicosTerceiros/SalvarServicos', 
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST", 
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    cache: false, 
    data: JSON.stringify({ 
            __RequestVerificationToken: gettoken(), 
            jsonString: todos_servicos
    }),
    success: function (data) { ...
```